# invoke function wrapped inside of anonymous function

Tags: javascript

To avoid variable collision and "everything" javascript experts say we should use self invoking function like the one below. But how can I reference it from outside. Or for example how can I invoke the foo function that is inside it?

onClick="foo()" // this doesn't work from outside !!!

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background: red;" id="dfg" onClick="foo()"></div>

<script>

(function () {
function foo(){
console.log("everything is OK")
}
}());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can add the method to window object.

```
(function (global) {

    global.foo = function(){
        console.log("everything is OK")
    }

}(window));

foo(); // everything is OK
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pF9w9/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Attaching events via onClick isn't really the way to go (you should be using addEventListener as Mohan Ahuja suggests), but if you must do it this way--here's how to do it:

```
(function () {
  function foo(){
    console.log("everything is OK")
  }
  window["foo"] = foo;
}());
```

You can't do the assignment outside the anonymous function--but anything you assign inside the anonymous function will work correctly.

Nevertheless, "onClick" is so 2002.  You should be using more modern methods.